# SQL Server allows you to drop a procedure that another procedure relies on?

Tags: sql-server

Given: stored procedure A calls stored procedure B

I can drop stored procedure B without SQL Server complaining.

Is there a setting that can prevent that from happening?

Comment: You can, but you would need to use `SCHEMABINDING`, which is only available in [Natively Compiled Stored Procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/creating-natively-compiled-stored-procedures?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)l which were introduced in SQL Server 2014 or 2016 (can't remember which).

Comment: @Larnu, if you add this as an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: My comment is really only a link only, @Rod . I've never used them either, or implemented them, so if this has worked and you managed it, I think you might be better off showing the steps yourself. :)